# Vue Material (steppers) : Prevent user from skipping steps + bind steps to a specific route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-material

Beginner question here :) I would like to create a stepper with 5 tabs, where you can't navigate to step 3 if you haven't completed step 2 (or step 4 if you haven't completed step 3, etc). If he's in step 4 and wants to come back to step 2, then all the other steps must be deactivated as well.

Also, how can I bind the steps to a specific route instead of putting the content iniside the md-step tags.

Hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my post help you out?

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your question you can mark it as correct, let me know if I can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your tabbers using `vue-router` you could construct a router guard that goes away and checks the current state for where the user is which would prevent the user from reaching that view. You'd also want to configure some kind of disabled state that shows where the user is so that the tabber icons can be generated dynamically. Though all of this is frontend so it's still not a silver bullet to your problem.

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards